# How can you use text in an excel cell and use it in the python script?

Tags: python-3.x

I have an excel file with text that I need python to read from and process it as part of the script without setting it to a variable.

if I have this script, it works fine

```
    dataframe_load = columns


    dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(
        Final_data,
        columns=
            dataframe_load                  
                ,
    )

  **  dataframe['CreatedDate']= pd.to_datetime(dataframe['CreatedDate'])**
```

however, if I put 'dataframe['CreatedDate']= pd.to_datetime(dataframe['CreatedDate'])' in an excel cell and have python read from it, it doesn't seem to work. How do I get it to output what's inside that variable in the script?

```
df = pd.read_csv(path, delimiter=',')
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    sf_object = row[0]
    table = row[1]
    query = row[2]
    columns = row[3].split(",")
    schema1 = row[4].split('\n')
    **dfcorrection = row[5]**

#...other script between this...#

    dataframe_load = columns


    dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(
        Final_data,
        columns=
            dataframe_load                  
                ,
    )

    **dfcorrection**
```

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, I figured it out

just had to make it exec(dfcorrection)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).